# Calculate and control number of mappers used by Hive query

Tags: hive, mapper

I have a Hive table t1 which has 104 files. Out of the 104 files 1 file is 61 MB and remaining 103 files are less than 1 MB. When I execute the query

```
select count(*) from t1
```

29 mappers are executed along with 1 reducer. I'm trying to figure out why 29 mappers and how can reduce the number of mappers?

```
mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize=256MB
mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize=1kb
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try Setting the mappers using below options

> set mapred.map.tasks = 20;

also check the total blocks of your data.

> hdfs dfs -du -s -h /apps/hive/warehouse//

Each block will be processed independently. Each mapper can be processed multiple blocks based on mapper numbers you are setting.